# What is the problem in my code when connecting to a database and outputting it to html and then to a website?

Tags: go

I wrote code in golango to connect to the database on the server and output the contents of the tables to the website. I also wrote code for the html output of the table. There are no problems and it connects, but the error "404 page not found" lights up on the web page. What is this error and what is the reason? This is the first time I've seen this

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "html/template"
    _ "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Жанр struct {
    idЖанр         int    
     Название_жанра string 
}

var database *sql.DB

func home_db(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     rows, err := database.Query("select * from newbd.Жанр")
     if err != nil {
         panic(err)
     }
     defer rows.Close()

     ganr := []Жанр{}
     for rows.Next() {
         p := Жанр{}
         err = rows.Scan(&p.idЖанр, &p.Название_жанра)
         if err != nil {
             panic(err)
             continue
         }
         ganr = append(ganr, p)
     }
     tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("home.html")
     tmpl.Execute(w, ganr)
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "xxxxx:xxxxxx@tcp(xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xx)/xxxxx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    fmt.Println("OK")
    http.HandleFunc("/dat/", home_db)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8100", nil)
}
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>RUMP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>idЖанр</th>
                <th>Название_жанра</th>
            </thead>
            {{range . }}
            <li>
                <td>{{.idЖанр}}</td>
                <td>{{.Название_жанра}}</td>
            </li>
            {{.end}}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: html  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RUMP</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead><th>idЖанр</th><th>Название_жанра</th><th></thead>
        {{range . }}
    <li>
        <td>{{.idЖанр}}</td>
        <td>{{.Название_жанра}}</td>
    </li>
    {{.end}}
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: (1) [Export](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field names in`Жанр`.  (2) Check and handle the errors returned from `template.ParseFiles` and `tmpl.Execute`.  The error returned from `tmpl.Execute` explains the problem.

Comment: The 404 error indicates that client is not connecting to correct server or using the correct path.